# How to store mongoose value as a date?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Everytime I save a date in Mongoose it ends up as a string.

```
    let newDate = new Date().toISOString();

    let thing = await Thing.findOne({});

    things.details.expirationDate = newDate;

    await thing.save();
```

I can confirm that in the database it is recognized as a string and not a date object.

How do I save this value on a date object? `thing.details` is a mixed schema type.

Comment: That's what `.toISOString()` does, it creates a string. You can do `let newDate = new Date()` to save the object as BSON directly

Comment: Cool, if you want to post that as an answer I will accept it. Thought I tried native dates earlier but doesn't look like it was working well, thx.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The method `.toISOString()` creates a string from the given date in the format

```
2016-10-05T14:48:00.000
```

and then that string is stored in the database, not an object

To store a date object, you can simply do

```
let newDate = new Date();
```

and Moongose should do the type conversion between javascripts `Date`  object and the `ISODate` generally used by MongoDB.

Comment: it does not happen to me. new Date() is stored as a String. In my model it looks like: 
`date : { type : Date, required : true, index: true  }`